# scipy function always returns a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, duck-typing, dynamic-typing

I'm encountering a scipy function that seems to return a numpy array no matter what's passed to it.  In my application I need to be able to pass scalars and lists only, so the only "problem" is that when I pass a scalar to the function an array with one element is returned (when I would expect a scalar). Should I ignore this behaviour, or hack up the function to ensure that when a scalar is passed a scalar is returned?

Example code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import scipy
import scipy.optimize
from numpy import cos

# This a some function we want to compute the inverse of
def f(x):
    y = x + 2*cos(x)
    return y

# Given y, this returns x such that f(x)=y
def f_inverse(y):

    # This will be zero if f(x)=y
    def minimize_this(x):
        return y-f(x)

    # A guess for the solution is required
    x_guess = y
    x_optimized = scipy.optimize.fsolve(minimize_this, x_guess) # THE PROBLEM COMES FROM HERE
    return x_optimized

# If I call f_inverse with a list, a numpy array is returned
print f_inverse([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
print type( f_inverse([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]) )

# If I call f_inverse with a tuple, a numpy array is returned
print f_inverse((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
print type( f_inverse((1.0, 2.0, 3.0)) )

# If I call f_inverse with a scalar, a numpy array is returned
print f_inverse(1.0)
print type( f_inverse(1.0) )

# This is the behaviour I expected (scalar passed, scalar returned).
# Adding [0] on the return value is a hackey solution (then thing would break if a list were actually passed).
print f_inverse(1.0)[0] # <- bad solution
print type( f_inverse(1.0)[0] )
```

On my system the output of this is:

```
[ 2.23872989  1.10914418  4.1187546 ]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[ 2.23872989  1.10914418  4.1187546 ]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[ 2.23872989]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
2.23872989209
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

I'm using SciPy 0.10.1 and Python 2.7.3 provided by MacPorts.

**SOLUTION**

After reading the answers below I settled on the following solution. Replace the return line in `f_inverse` with:

```
if(type(y).__module__ == np.__name__):
    return x_optimized
else:
    return type(y)(x_optimized)
```

Here `return type(y)(x_optimized)` causes the return type to be the same as the type the function was called with. Unfortunately this does not work if y is a numpy type, so `if(type(y).__module__ == np.__name__)` is used to [detect numpy types using the idea presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569452/how-to-identify-numpy-types-in-python/12569453#12569453) and exclude them from the type conversion.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on SciPy 0.7.2; I get a scalar back of type `np.float64`. Btw., those aren't lists that `optimize.fsolve` is returning; they're Numpy arrays.

Comment: Yes you're right. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the implementation in `scipy.optimize.fsolve` is:

`x0 = array(x0, ndmin=1)`

This means that your scalar will be turned into a 1-element sequence, and your 1-element sequence will be essentially unchanged.

The fact that it seems to work is an implementation detail, and I would refactor your code to not allow sending a scalar into `fsolve`.  I know this might seem to go against duck-typing, but the function asks for an `ndarray` for that argument, so you should respect the interface to be robust to changes in implementation.  I don't, however, see any problem with conditionally using `x_guess = array(y, ndmin=1)` for converting scalars into an `ndarray` in your wrapper function and converting the result back to scalar when necessary.

Here is the relevant part of docstring of `fsolve` function:

> ```
> def fsolve(func, x0, args=(), fprime=None, full_output=0,
>            col_deriv=0, xtol=1.49012e-8, maxfev=0, band=None,
>            epsfcn=0.0, factor=100, diag=None):
>     """
>     Find the roots of a function.
>
>     Return the roots of the (non-linear) equations defined by
>     ``func(x) = 0`` given a starting estimate.
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     func : callable f(x, *args)
>         A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument.
>     x0 : ndarray
>         The starting estimate for the roots of ``func(x) = 0``.
>
>     ----SNIP----
>
>     Returns
>     -------
>     x : ndarray
>         The solution (or the result of the last iteration for
>         an unsuccessful call).
>
>     ----SNIP----
> ```

Comment: Quite a few SciPy functions accept "array-like" input and will convert that to arrays implicitly. +1 for the docstring, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure what to do with this though, because I don't know if it's safe to ignore the difference between a scalar and a numpy array with one element.

Comment: In this case I think it's not safe, so my answer is you should indeed hack up your `f_inverse` function if you _really_ want the interface of scalar-in scalar-out.

Comment: Yes rereading your answer I see that's implied. I'll accept this answer if nothing "nicer" comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can convert Numpy arrays to lists and Numpy scalars to Python scalars:

```
>>> x = np.float32(42)
>>> type(x)
<type 'numpy.float32'>
>>> x.tolist()
42.0
```

In other words, the `tolist` method on `np.ndarray` handles scalars specially.

That still leaves you with single-element lists, but those are easy enough to handle in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

I guess wims answer really already says it mostly, but maybe this makes the differences clearer.

The scalar returned by numpy should with `array[0]` should be (almost?) fully compatible to the standard python float:

```
a = np.ones(2, dtype=float)
isinstance(a[0], float) == True # even this is true.
```

For the  most part already the 1 sized array is compatible to both a scalar and list, though for example it is a mutable object while the float is not:

```
a = np.ones(1, dtype=float)
import math
math.exp(a) # works
# it is not isinstance though
isinstance(a, float) == False
# The 1-sized array works sometimes more like number:
bool(np.zeros(1)) == bool(np.asscalar(np.zeros(1)))
# While lists would be always True if they have more then one element.
bool([0]) != bool(np.zeros(1))

# And being in place might create confusion:
a = np.ones(1); c = a; c += 3
b = 1.; c = b; c += 3
a != b
```

So if the user should not know about it, I think the first is fine the second it is dangerous.

You can also use `np.asscalar(result)` to convert a size 1 array (of any dimension) to the correct python scalar:

In [29]: type(np.asscalar(a[0]))
   Out[29]: float

If you want to make sure there are no surprises for a user who is not supposed to know about numpy, you will have to at least get the 0's element if a scalar was passed in. If the user should be numpy aware, just documentation is probably as good.

Comment: The `isinstance` check works because the OP is passing in Python floats: `isinstance(np.float64(1), float)` is true, but `isinstance(np.float32(1), float)` is false.

Comment: True, but a python float is always double, if someone actually passes in `np.float32(1)` they should know to expect numpy objects back.

Answer (score 1):

As @wim pointed out, `fsolve` transforms your scalar into a `ndarray` of shape `(1,)` and returns an array of shape `(1,)`.

If you really want to get a scalar as output, you could try to put the following at the end of your function:

```
if solution.size == 1:
    return solution.item()
return solution
```

(The `item` method copies an element of an array and return a standard Python scalar)