# How to identify numpy types in python?

Tags: python, numpy, duck-typing, dynamic-typing

How can one reliably determine if an object has a numpy type?

I realize that this question goes against the philosophy of duck typing, but idea is to make sure a function (which uses scipy and numpy) never returns a numpy type unless it is called with a numpy type.  [This comes up in the solution to another question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565735/scipy-function-always-returns-a-numpy-array) but I think the general problem of determining if an object has a numpy type is far enough away from that original question that they should be separated.

Comment: One question: If you (or, say, scipy) define a type that subclasses a numpy type, should that count or not? (I believe you can't subclass numpy types in Python, but you can in a C module, and I think you can also subclass numpypy types in PyPy… so it probably doesn't matter, but it's not inconceivable that it could.)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that; basically your comment points out that the question is more difficult than expected. Honestly that kind of high-level consideration is way overkill for my situation. For the general and portable answer, I would say that as long as the behaviour is defined then it's OK.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use the builtin `type` function to get the type, then you can use the `__module__` property to find out where it was defined:

```
>>> import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(a)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(a).__module__
'numpy'
>>> type(a).__module__ == np.__name__
True
```

Comment: is e.g. numpy.ma.MaskedArray not a numpy enough type?

Comment: If you want anything in numpy.* you just walk the parent package of the module. (At that point, you obviously want to wrap it in a function.) And if you want pandas DataFrames to count as numpyish, add an or to test for that. And so on. The point is, you have to know what you're actually asking for when you want to do something as unusual as loose manual type switching, but once you know, it's easy to implement.

Comment: This solution seems very unpythonic, relying on hidden attributes. But maybe that is just a matter of taste?

Comment: @j08lue They’re not hidden attributes, they’re documented special attributes. It is, nevertheless, unpythonic, but I think that’s inherent in the problem. (And I think it’s a strength of Python that when you want to do something the language discourages, the best solution is usually visibly ugly enough to call out that you’re doing something that’s normally a bad idea.)

Answer (score 122):

The solution I've come up with is:

```
isinstance(y, (np.ndarray, np.generic) )
```

However, [it's not 100% clear](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.generic.html?highlight=generic#numpy.generic) that all numpy types are guaranteed to be either `np.ndarray` or `np.generic`, and this probably isn't version robust.

Comment: I suppose you could filter `dir(numpy)` on types and builtin functions (and classes, but I don't think it has any) and use that to generate a tuple to `isinstance` against, which would be robust. (I believe you can pass builtin functions to isinstance whether they're actually type constructors or not, but you'd have to check that.)

Comment: Yes, they should all be subclasses of those two AFAIK.

Comment: @seberg Thanks. It certainly seems to be the case for now, but the python documentation [isn't very clear on this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.generic.html?highlight=generic#numpy.generic) and it could conceivably change in the future.

Answer (score 29):

Old question but I came up with a definitive answer with an example. Can't hurt to keep questions fresh as I had this same problem and didn't find a clear answer. The key is to make sure you have `numpy` imported, and then run the `isinstance` bool.  While this may seem simple, if you are doing some computations across different data types, this small check can serve as a quick test before your start some numpy vectorized operation.

```python
##################
# important part!
##################

import numpy as np

####################
# toy array for demo
####################

arr = np.asarray(range(1,100,2))

########################
# The instance check
######################## 

isinstance(arr,np.ndarray)
```

Comment: Why do you say this is definitive? This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/12569453/1066291, which was written 4 years before this answer, where the author points to documentation indicating that it isn't definitive.

Answer (score 12):

That actually depends on what you're looking for.

- If you want to test whether a sequence is actually a `ndarray`, a `isinstance(..., np.ndarray)` is probably the easiest. Make sure you don't reload numpy in the background as the module may be different, but otherwise, you should be OK. `MaskedArrays`, `matrix`, `recarray` are all subclasses of `ndarray`, so you should be set.
- If you want to test whether a scalar is a numpy scalar, things get a bit more complicated. You could check whether it has a `shape` and a `dtype` attribute. You can compare its `dtype` to the basic dtypes, whose list you can find in `np.core.numerictypes.genericTypeRank`. Note that the elements of this list are strings, so you'd have to do a `tested.dtype is np.dtype(an_element_of_the_list)`...

Comment: +1. If you're actually looking for something besides "is a `numpy` type", and can define what that something is, this is better than the other answers. And in most cases, you _should_ be looking for something specific that you can define.

Answer (score 8):

To get the type, use the builtin `type` function. With the `in` operator, you can test if the type is a numpy type by checking if it contains the string `numpy`;

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [3]: type(a)
Out[3]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [4]: 'numpy' in str(type(a))
Out[4]: True
```

(This example was run in [IPython](http://ipython.org/), by the way. Very handy for interactive use and quick tests.)

Comment: This works, but if you define a type called, say, "numpygroup", you'll get false positives. Also, depending on the string representation of types is a bad idea if you can avoid it—and in this case, you can. Look at its module instead.

Comment: Using the module is indeed a better solution.

Comment: Regex could be used

Comment: @Omkaar.K Regex could be used for what? To do the exact same check in a slightly more complicated way?

Comment: @abamert "Could" is what I said, also regex could look complicated for simple tasks like these, but it is extremely useful for large string processing tasks, So it is not a bad idea to learn it. I guess you know that already since your portfolio portrays you as a senior programmer?

Answer (score 7):

Note that the `type(numpy.ndarray)` is a `type` itself and watch out for boolean and scalar types.  Don't be too discouraged if it's not intuitive or easy, it's a pain at first.

See also:
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html
- https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-data/tree/master/numpy-mypy

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.ndarray
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(np.ndarray)
<class 'type'>
>>> a = np.linspace(1,25)
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(a) == type(np.ndarray)
False
>>> type(a) == np.ndarray
True
>>> isinstance(a, np.ndarray)
True
```

Fun with booleans:

```
>>> b = a.astype('int32') == 11
>>> b[0]
False
>>> isinstance(b[0], bool)
False
>>> isinstance(b[0], np.bool)
False
>>> isinstance(b[0], np.bool_)
True
>>> isinstance(b[0], np.bool8)
True
>>> b[0].dtype == np.bool
True
>>> b[0].dtype == bool  # python equivalent
True
```

More fun with scalar types, see:
- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in

```
>>> x = np.array([1,], dtype=np.uint64)
>>> x[0].dtype
dtype('uint64')
>>> isinstance(x[0], np.uint64)
True
>>> isinstance(x[0], np.integer)
True  # generic integer
>>> isinstance(x[0], int)
False  # but not a python int in this case

# Try matching the `kind` strings, e.g.
>>> np.dtype('bool').kind                                                                                           
'b'
>>> np.dtype('int64').kind                                                                                          
'i'
>>> np.dtype('float').kind                                                                                          
'f'
>>> np.dtype('half').kind                                                                                           
'f'

# But be weary of matching dtypes
>>> np.integer
<class 'numpy.integer'>
>>> np.dtype(np.integer)
dtype('int64')
>>> x[0].dtype == np.dtype(np.integer)
False

# Down these paths there be dragons:

# the .dtype attribute returns a kind of dtype, not a specific dtype
>>> isinstance(x[0].dtype, np.dtype)
True
>>> isinstance(x[0].dtype, np.uint64)
False  
>>> isinstance(x[0].dtype, np.dtype(np.uint64))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
# yea, don't go there
>>> isinstance(x[0].dtype, np.int_)
False  # again, confusing the .dtype with a specific dtype


# Inequalities can be tricky, although they might
# work sometimes, try to avoid these idioms:

>>> x[0].dtype <= np.dtype(np.uint64)
True
>>> x[0].dtype <= np.dtype(np.float)
True
>>> x[0].dtype <= np.dtype(np.half)
False  # just when things were going well
>>> x[0].dtype <= np.dtype(np.float16)
False  # oh boy
>>> x[0].dtype == np.int
False  # ya, no luck here either
>>> x[0].dtype == np.int_
False  # or here
>>> x[0].dtype == np.uint64
True  # have to end on a good note!
```