# Difficulty determining the type of a numpy int64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**question**

I'm having trouble identifying `numpy.int64` objects, in order to convert them to base python int for json serialisation. `isinstance` usually works but does not in the following example, and I would love to understand why this is.

```
>>> x
0
>>> type(x)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
>>> import numpy
>>> isinstance(x, numpy.int64)
False
```

**context**

x in the above comes from my application, generated by `to_dict` on a pandas dataframe. Various dataframes are used to generate the result, hence why I can't just use pandas `to_json` instead.

taking hints from [How to identify numpy types in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569452/how-to-identify-numpy-types-in-python/40066238#40066238), I've actually managed to sucessfully detect these items (which sometimes aren't numpy objects at all), using the following:

```
>>> (isinstance(x, (pd.np.ndarray, pd.np.generic)) and 
>>> pd.np.issubdtype(x, pd.np.dtype('int64')))
True
```

but I would appreciate very much if someone could explain why the first option doesn't work, so that I can be confident enough to deploy this into our production system. Using `simplejson` and a custom `JSONDecoder` class which uses `isinstance(obj, pd.np.int64)` has worked for months, but it has suddenly stopped working with the example above.

`pickle.dumps(x)` gives `b'\x80\x03cnumpy.core.multiarray\nscalar\nq\x00cnumpy\ndtype\nq\x01X\x02\x00\x00\x00i8q\x02K\x00K\x01\x87q\x03Rq\x04(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x05NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x06bC\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x07\x86q\x08Rq\t.'`

interestingly, pickling the object seems to fix the issue.

```
>>> isinstance(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(x)), pd.np.int64)
True
```

Comment: what's your python setup? (version, etc...) I cannot reproduce on anaconda python 3.6 (windows 64 bit)

Comment: have you tried `type(x) == np.int64`? also why do you have a numpy type before importing numpy?

Comment: Python 3.4.3 (default, Aug 20 2015, 14:15:05)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux

Comment: `type(x) == np.int64` is `False`

Comment: pd.__version__ = '0.18.1', and pd.np.__version__ = '1.11.0'

Comment: Is this a repeatable example?  It will hard for us to help unless we can generate the problem object as well.  There's no way of knowing why/how the original `x` is different from the `pickle` round trip.

Comment: I tried pickling it to create a reproducible example, but was surprised that after pickling it worked. So I'm having trouble reproducing. @hpaulj is there some way I can interrogate x that might show up the difference before and after?

Comment: It's barely possible that you have two numpys installed, and the code that creates `x` here is somehow picking up a different one than you get when you `import numpy` later.

Comment: Check `pd.np.__file__` and `numpy.__file__`.

Comment: @RobertKern `pd.np.__file__` = 
`'/home/vagrant/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'` and `numpy.__file__` is the same

Comment: And `pd.np is numpy`?

Comment: Have you done any module reloading? That can cause fun issues like this.

Comment: yes @RobertKern, tracing through the program I can see the problematic items were read from the database using pandas, processed, pickled then written to redis (as a caching layer). They are then recovered, processed some more, and then the problem occurs when I try to write the result. I can see how this can cause issues, but I have the end to end process running in debug from pycharm using the same virtual machine (through vagrant), same runtime and same libraries (confirmed in both places using `__file__`. It worked fine for months. Not easy to debug! Anything else I can compare perhaps?

Comment: Set aside the `__file__` thing. Focus on the identity comparison: `pd.np is numpy`. If Python ends up importing the same module twice and doesn't realize that it's already imported, then you'll get problems like this (even if it's importing from the same files). If you are running this service via a web framework that automatically reloads modules (e.g. for development), it's possible that it accidentally reloaded the `numpy` module, creating two different `numpy.int64` types.

Comment: Thanks @RobertKern, I think that must be the cause of the issue, and so I now understand why `pd.np.issubdtype` is a more suitable way to detect these items. Cheers for your help!