# Clean way to return a one-element Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a clean way to write functions that return a one-element numpy array as the element itself?

Let's say I want to vectorize a simple square function and I want my return value to be the same dtype as my input. I could write something like this:

```
def foo(x):
    result = np.square(x)
    if len(result) == 1:
        return result[0]
    return result
```

or

```
def foo(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x**2
    return np.square(x)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? So that I can use this function both for scalars and for arrays?

I know that I can check the dtype of my input directly and use IF statements to make it work, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: This a question for StackOverflow, but here is a hint: please clarify how your desired results differ from the default NumPy behaviour, _e.g._ for `np.square(2.)` and `np.square([2.])` and `np.square([1,2,3])`. Also, try to show the outputs from your own code examples for the same inputs.

Comment: Would this work for you - `(x**2).squeeze()`?

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure whether or not I fully understood the question, but maybe something like this would help?

```
def square(x):
    if 'numpy' in str(type(x)):
        return np.square(x)
    else:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return list(np.square(x))
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return int(np.square(x))
        if isinstance(x, float):
            return float(np.square(x))
```

I defined some test cases:

```
np_array_one = np.array([3.4])
np_array_mult = np.array([3.4, 2, 6])
int_ = 5
list_int = [2, 4, 2.9]
float_ = float(5.3)
list_float = [float(4.5), float(9.1), float(7.5)]

examples = [np_array_one, np_array_mult, int_, list_int, float_, list_float]
```

So we can see how the function behaves.

```
for case in examples:
    print 'Input type: {}.'.format(type(case))
    out = square(case)
    print out
    print 'Output type: {}'.format(type(out))
    print '-----------------'
```

And the output:

```
Input type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>.
[ 11.56]
Output type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
-----------------
Input type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>.
[ 11.56   4.    36.  ]
Output type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
-----------------
Input type: <type 'int'>.
25
Output type: <type 'int'>
-----------------
Input type: <type 'list'>.
[4.0, 16.0, 8.4100000000000001]
Output type: <type 'list'>
-----------------
Input type: <type 'float'>.
28.09
Output type: <type 'float'>
-----------------
Input type: <type 'list'>.
[20.25, 82.809999999999988, 56.25]
Output type: <type 'list'>
-----------------
```

From the test cases, the input and output is always same. However, the function is not really clean.

I used some of the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569452/how-to-identify-numpy-types-in-python) at SO.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I know how I could make it work but I was interested in knowing if there was any type of clean way to do this, perhaps some Python magic I wasn't aware of before

Comment: Then maybe try to ask directly on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a very good reason to want that. (Could you explain why you need this?)

All the clients of this function will have to check if the result is an array or a single element or will have to convert it to an array.
Typically you also get very elegant code if you iterate over all elements of an array, even if it is just one element.

Unless it always has to be a single element (this is a conversion function), but then the return statement should throw an exception instead on empty/long arrays.

Apart from that, the code you have is perfectly understandable/readable. Any smart trick to 'improve' it would be a mental burden each time the future you or a colleague has to read it.

-- edit

I see your point. Probably you already ran into the problem that len(1) is not allowed (int/float do not have len()), so you could do a type check on the input argument. E.g.

```
if (type(x) == list) ...
```

Comment: Essentially, I want my function to output the same type as my input, so if I input a single element (let's say a float), I want a float back, if I input a numpy array of floats, that's what I want back. My problem is that for instance my function has something like np.square(x), it will transform my float into a an array. So I guess that I would want to have two functions into one (float->float, array->array)